# SnowFlake Azure Event Grid Integration - Does it doe a file scan?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to figure out how the SnowPipes execute when you setup Snowflake to automatically import data using Azure event grid notification, like this document describes - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-azure.html

So say I have a Azure Data Lake Gen2 container attached to Snowflake as an external stage, and this container has three folders (FolderA, FolderB, and FolderC), and I have a SnowPipe setup for each folder.  Then I add a file to FolderA.  So Snowflake gets a message from Azure Event Grid saying that the file has been added (and the Event Grid message has the full file name).  Does Snowflake know to just run the SnowPipe setup for FolderA?  Or will it run all three of the SnowPipes?  And when the SnowPipe runs, does it scan for files?  Or does the SnowPipe just import the specific file named in the EventGrid message?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up event grid and snowpipe and overall handshake process in Azure/Snowflake combination is a bit tricky and have never tried with multiple folders and snowpipe but I prefer to give folder and file pattern to make sure even if snowpipe is triggered it only picks the files which is targeted for copy command which snowpipe has wrapped.

In AWS, all snowpipe with auto-ingest true flag generates the same ARN key and SNS (equivalent to even grid) also takes the file pattern on each folder and calls the same ARN. So I assume it runs but does not copy anything.

But I will surely try and simulate how it works.